# Image not getting displayed from the "if" clause

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I want a particular image to be displayed for a corresponding text
 So I tried like below in my increase()

```
    TextView hedng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemheading);
    if(hedng.getText() == "HEADING OF THE TOPIC"){
        ImageView lvlm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.levelimg);
        lvlm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
```

But the image is not being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView hedng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemheading);
if(hedng.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("HEADING OF THE TOPIC")){
    ImageView lvlm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.levelimg);
    lvlm.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
```

Comment: Still it's displaying nothing

Comment: Show me the xml and also show me exact condition in if(<"string??">)

Comment: Oh sorry it is getting displayed. Had a small typoas. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean by "image not getting displayed". You probably want to use [setImageDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) instead.

```
Resources resources = getResources();
lvlm.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```